# Adding a second network interface on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to add a second network interface to Ubuntu 18.04 instance on Amazon EC2. I followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-secondary-network-interface/) from Amazon on how to do it, and added a /etc/netplan/51-eth1.yaml file with the following content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      addresses:
       - 172.31.10.13/20
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0
         via: 172.31.0.1
         scope: link
         table: 1001
      routing-policy:
        - from: 172.31.10.13
          table: 1001
```

So my routing table now looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

However, pinging an address on the same subnet using ping -I works only from the eth1 interface. I do see the replies arriving correctly on eth0, but it looks like the OS ignores them for some reason. 
Running a ping on eth0 together with tcpdump on the same interface I get the following output:

```
PING 172.31.5.193 (172.31.5.193) from 172.31.10.197 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
06:00:15.186249 02:bb:3e:8f:3f:1c > 02:29:0b:80:74:b4, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.31.10.197 > 172.31.5.193: ICMP echo request, id 3538, seq 1, length 64
06:00:15.186635 02:29:0b:80:74:b4 > 02:bb:3e:8f:3f:1c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.31.5.193 > 172.31.10.197: ICMP echo reply, id 3538, seq 1, length 64
06:00:16.201069 02:bb:3e:8f:3f:1c > 02:29:0b:80:74:b4, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.31.10.197 > 172.31.5.193: ICMP echo request, id 3538, seq 2, length 64
06:00:16.201513 02:29:0b:80:74:b4 > 02:bb:3e:8f:3f:1c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.31.5.193 > 172.31.10.197: ICMP echo reply, id 3538, seq 2, length 64
^C
--- 172.31.5.193 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1030ms
```

So all addresses are correct, but the packets are still regarded as lost. The same thing happens with TCP connections on the interface - the SYN-ACK arrives but ignored. I have verified that iptables rules are accept by default, and no other rules exist. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why do you need 2 NICs on the *same* subnet? That’s hardly ever needed.

If you simply need *2 Private IPs or 2 Elastic IPs* you can assign the *secondary* one on the existing interface: [**Secondary Private IP Address**](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-private-ip-address/)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I wanted to test Multipath TCP, but it turns out it works just as well with another IP address on the same interface. Still curious as to why the two interfaces didn't work though.

Comment: no help here. come back another day.